# Conditional subsetting of a data frame R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

Let the data frame be:

```
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(name=sample(LETTERS,260,replace=TRUE),
               hobby=rep(c("outdoor","indoor"),260),chess=rnorm(1:10))
```

and the condition which I will use to extract from df be:

```
df_cond<-df %>% group_by(name,hobby) %>%
    summarize(count=n()) %>%
    mutate(sum.var=sum(count),sum.name=length(name)) %>%
    filter(sum.name==2) %>%
    mutate(min.var=min(count)) %>%
    mutate(use=ifelse(min.var==count,"yes","no")) %>%
    filter(grepl("yes",use))
```

I want to randomly extract the rows from `df` that correspond to the  (name,hobby,count) combination in `df_cond` along with the rest of `df`. I am having bit of a trouble combining `%in%` and `sample`.Thanks for any clue!

Edit: For example:

```
head(df_cond)
         name   hobby count sum.var sum.name min.var   use
      <fctr>  <fctr> <int>   <int>    <int>   <int> <chr>
    1      A  indoor     2       6        2       2   yes
    2      B  indoor     8      16        2       8   yes
    3      B outdoor     8      16        2       8   yes
    4      C outdoor     6      14        2       6   yes
    5      D  indoor    10      24        2      10   yes
    6      E outdoor     8      18        2       8   yes
```

Using the above data frame, I want to randomly extract 2 rows (=count) with the combination A+indoor(row1) from `df`,
8 rows with the combination B+indoor (row 2) from `df` ....and so on.

Combining @denrous and @Jacob answers to get what I need. like so:

```
m2<-df_cond %>% 
    mutate(data = map2(name, hobby, function(x, y) {df %>% filter(name == x, hobby == y)})) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    select(data) %>% 
    unnest()



test<-m2 %>% 
group_by(name,hobby) %>% 
summarize(num.levels=length(unique(hobby))) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
group_by(name) %>% 
summarize(total_levels=sum(num.levels)) %>% 
filter(total_levels>1)

fin<-semi_join(m2,test)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could use `purrr` to achieve what you want:

```
df_cond %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(name, hobby, function(x, y) {filter(df, name == x, hobby == y)})) %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data, count, function(x, y) sample_n(x, size = y)))
```

And if you want the same form as df:

```
df_cond %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(name, hobby, function(x, y) {df %>% filter(name == x, hobby == y)})) %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data, count, function(x, y) sample_n(x, size = y))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(data) %>% 
  unnest()
```

Comment: great ! need to start using purrr more often.

Comment: this doesn't get me what I need but close enough. Thanks! Will post a final solution later.

Answer (score 1):

Edited based on OP clarification.

There has to better way but I'd use a loop:

```
library(dplyr)

master_df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(df_cond)){
  name = as.character(df_cond[i, 1])
  hobby = as.character(df_cond[i, 2])
  n = as.numeric(df_cond[i, 3])

  temp_df <- df %>% filter(name == name, hobby == hobby)
  temp_df <- sample_n(temp_df, n)
  master_df <- rbind(master_df, temp_df)
      }
```

Comment: Thanks...but this was not exactly what I was looking for. I have tried to clarify the question.

Comment: I can see the principle on how this works but it is not giving the correct output.  I have combined yours and @denrous answers to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear if this is exactly what you want, but you may be looking for `left_join`:

```
df %>% 
    left_join(df_cond, by = "name")
```

Comment: I do not really want a join. What I want is to randomly sample from df the # of rows (defined by 'count' and the combination name + hobby in  df_cond. I will add an example to clarify the question.